# Mapping two buttons press as a 3rd button

Tags: basic, delay, button, timing

I got a cheap controller with only 5 buttons. I thought about soldering a few more in parallel so that pressing any of the additional buttons would trigger some other two buttons simultaneously. Then I would use JoyToKey or LLJoy to map those buttons pressed together as a separate command.

But to make it work, I need one of those buttons to get "pressed" a bit earlier than the other. I guess introducing a delay to one of the connected buttons is the way to do this, but I'm unsure exactly how. Was looking into NE555, but it says you need to power it with 5V or more, and the controller is powered by two AAA batteries. Which is also the reason I wouldn't want to use microcontrollers or really anything that would need its own power supply.

Is there a way to get a small delay with a transistor or optocoupler maybe?

Comment: An RC delay could work.  If those buttons have any hardware debounce, just changing the values on one might do the trick.

Comment: why do you need one button to be pressed before the other?

Comment: Can't you use diodes to combine button presses?

Comment: LLJoy lets you assign double press as a separate command only when it's done in a particular order.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what do you mean by combining them with diodes. Are you talking about multiplexing?

Comment: With RC delay I am afraid that upon releasing it will also take some time for the delayed button to go low, and because of the way both LLJoy and JoyToKey work both buttons have to be released at the same time, otherwise it'll register a separate command.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry, not sure what do you mean by combining them with diodes. Are you talking about multiplexing?

If your buttons are connected between signal and ground (with a pull-up) you can often use a set of diodes to make a combined button:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fViEWU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This does not work if your buttons are in a 'button scan matrix'.